# Who is the fat man in red on the Elene royal council?

Tags: david-eddings

Rereading *The Elenium*, I noticed for the first time an unnamed member of the royal council: a fat man in red whom Sparhawk doesn’t recognize, and who never speaks, and who is never again mentioned after he’s thrown into the dungeon along with the deposed Prince Regent.

> *The Earl of Lenda, a white-haired man in his seventies, was dressed in
>   a soft grey doublet, and he was grinning openly, his bright blue eyes
>   sparkling in his lined face. The Baron Harparin, a notorious pederast,
>   sat with an astonished expression on his face. His clothing was a riot
>   of conflicting colours. **Seated next to him was a grossly fat man in
>   red whom Sparhawk did not recognize.***

**Who is this man in red? Was this an in-joke of sorts, perhaps a real-life reference?**

Comment: Hard to say.  There's no trove of outside information on most of Edding's books.  Probably just a cliché toady for the regent, given minimal character by his visual appearance... but I've got nothing to support that either.

Comment: Just a generic "noble", as far as I can tell.

Comment: The fact that he did not recognize a member of the council was probably just a way to reinforce in your mind how long he had been away.  It shows that the political landscape had shifted in the time he was away and that he was no longer well informed about the political climate.

Comment: @ David Cram - I think promote your comment to answer. We are never told his name and his purpose was as you say.